# Percentage top value showing wrong computed value in chrome [possible bug!]

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I created an element dynamically in jquery added it to page, added class to it which gives it `top:50%`. Everything is fine, it's at 50%, but when i get value of top like this `.css('top')` i get wrong value, 470 instead of 20. The problem is, this wrong value even though not applied causes error in effect i am trying to get which relies on getting correct value via javascript.. **This is no problem in firefox**. I get what i see and what's computed.

**Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/dbj2un2e/**

`d.css( 'top', d.css('top') );` **changes the actual position in chrome**. (uncomment to see its affect)

Screenshot to explain little further. (open image in new tab to see it clearly)

[image]

Comment: you'll need to recreate this in a fiddle or post a link for anyone to know what's actually happening.

Comment: yea, i was able to reproduce it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use `position().top` instead of `css('top')`

```
var d = $('<div>').addClass('zzz');

$('.abc').append(d);

console.log(d.position().top);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbj2un2e/2/)